# Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport Store Visible Layers on Page Reload

Tags: javascript, php, html, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

It's been difficult for me to clarify this post...

I am extending a Leaflet map using the following plugins:

- Leaflet.MarkerCluster
- Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport

My page has a header div and a map div. The header contains a HTML 5 form that, passes GET variables, reloads the page, and executes a SQL Server query that retrieves my pins/clusters.

Every time the form is submitted, the page reloads and the visible layers of the Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport plugin are re-checked (see red rectangle in linked picture).

***Essentially, the check boxes in the red rectangle are always checked when the page refreshes, but I want them to load in the same state they were in when the form's submit button is clicked.***

[image: My Map]

Is there any way to easily store a cookie or pass variables that save which layers are checked (visible) and load them in that state when the page is reloaded? The layer control is primarily generated by the plugin, not my own code.

[image: Control Code]

Thank you very much,

Nick

Comment: Looks like you might rather have 2 instances of standard Layers Control. Why not!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard Leaflet Layers Control, it monitors the layers that are added to or removed from the map, and ticks / unticks the checkboxes accordingly.

Therefore it is just a matter of properly re-adding (or in your case, *not* adding) the layers that were previously unchecked by the user.

As to retrieve which layers were unchecked / removed from map, it is up to you to choose the implementation. Since you are already submitting an HTML form, you could very well send some extra values that tell those removed layers, and send them back to the client in the new page.

A more modern approach would avoid refreshing the page and use an AJAX scheme.

However, looking at your screenshot, it looks like you may not be using the standard Layers Control. In that case, it would depend on how that Control actually works.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I am not using the standard layers control, I'm using a plugin that handles the layers itself. Unfortunately, I'm sort of rebuilding a map that was created by someone else and they did a very poor job of structuring things. I added the plugin's source code for the layer check boxes to my original post above.